# When did Tarvek and Anevka first know about and participate in Aaronev's fatal experiments on Spark girls?

Tags: girl-genius

In *Girl Genius*, we know that by the time Agatha passes by Balan's Gap and falls into Aaronev's clutches, both Tarvek *and* Anevka are involved in his 'trapping' and the experimentation on Spark girls.

However, is there any information, from either the comics themselves, or any supplemental material (novels, The Works, radio shows, author interviews etc) regarding the *timeline* of Tarvek and Anevka's involvement, specially as relating to Tarvek's stay in Paris and the experimentation on Anevka?

Basic information regarding whether Tarvek knew before he left for Paris, or if Anevka knew before she was experimented on, and how the two (Tarvek in Paris and the Anevka experiment) relate to each other in terms of timeline, is also acceptable in absence of greater detail. :)

Answer (score 2):

**Not yet.**

The only thing that can be said for certain on that sequence of events is that Tarvek was on-hand or nearby when Anevka went through Aaronev's Summoning Engine, as he is shown in one panel [observing his father distraught over her bed](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20060911).  It also seemed to be after he came back from Paris, unless he had a very short stay there; Master Payne stated [Tinka was taken 3 years ago](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20050930), and Tarvek confirmed [he modeled the new body after her](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20051104). Given both that he needs to maintain "Anevka's" body and that many shenanigans were had in Paris, it's likely he was home for good at that point.

I can speculate that both Tarvek and Anevka helped their father when they couldn't avoid it, that family being as disjointed as it is. Tarvek seemed to only be interested in keeping his father stable so that the city and his own plans wouldn't fall apart, so he likely got involved at points just enough to stay on his good side.  Anevka may have helped more than Tarvek, as she was far more interested in how she could turn the work towards her own ambition, and had [her sadistic side](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/comic.php?date=20051128).  Seeing as she was most harmed by it, it's understandable, but it's hard to know how much of this is attributable to Anevka's original personality, rather than the artificial copy that Tarvek admitted wasn't perfect. Since 90% of the Sturmhalten arc is half-truths and lies and politics, most of this is just guesswork though.  The most reliable source is the only survivor, Tarvek, and most of the lies are his; we only know as much as we do because he *seems* more honest when in Castle Heterodyne, at rock-bottom and having already lost most everything.

Still speculating, but we can be pretty sure that Anevka didn't volunteer, given past results.  I can almost see Anevka being put through as some sort of last-ditch desperation, since nothing else had worked.  Maybe he saw his daughter as a trade. I dunno. As for previous results, the actual collection and kidnapping of girls may have been mostly handled by the Geisterdamen, who allied with Aaronev, had much more drive to see the Summoning succeed, and had more mobility around all the emptier spaces of Europe.  Publicly known nobles can only hush up so much about their travels and actions, and while I can see Anevka indulging, Tarvek doesn't seem the type to take the risk.

The novels highlight a few new details but I don't see anything new or related to the Sturmhalten family in particular. (Still reading through however)

That said, the main plot of the comic has actually returned to Paris (as of time of writing this) so light may be shed on quite a lot of past events, since so many of our main characters have had a history there (at last count, Tarvek, Gil, Othar, Bang was in the area, and the novels state Barry sent a letter from Paris after he left)

Comment: If the plot does shed new light soon, I will edit the answer as needed.

Comment: It is worthy of note that the Castle seems telepathic.  That means Agatha is going to (eventually) have access to that.  It also means that the castle does have access to that.